# Android Path shape not filled properly

Tags: android, canvas, path, drawable

I created a custom rectangle shape with path where you can control how to draw all corners: not rounded, rounded "inside"(it's ordinary rounded corners), rounded "outside"(see picture). Code:

```
enum class CornerType {
    NOT_ROUNDED,
    ROUNDED_INSIDE,
    ROUNDED_OUTSIDE
}

object CustomShapes {

    fun rectangleWithRoundedCorners(path: Path, rect: Rect, cornerRadius: Int,
                                    topLeft: CornerType, topRight: CornerType,
                                    bottomLeft: CornerType, bottomRight: CornerType){

        val topLeftX = when(topLeft){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> rect.left
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> rect.left + cornerRadius
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> rect.left - cornerRadius
        }.toFloat()
        val topLeftY = rect.top.toFloat()

        val topRightX = when(topRight){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> rect.right
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> rect.right - cornerRadius
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> rect.right + cornerRadius
        }.toFloat()
        val topRightY = rect.top.toFloat()

        val bottomLeftX = when(bottomLeft){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> rect.left
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> rect.left + cornerRadius
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> rect.left - cornerRadius
        }.toFloat()
        val bottomLeftY = rect.bottom.toFloat()

        val bottomRightX = when(bottomRight){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> rect.right
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> rect.right - cornerRadius
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> rect.right + cornerRadius
        }.toFloat()
        val bottomRightY = rect.bottom.toFloat()


        path.reset()
        //1
        path.moveTo(topLeftX, topLeftY)
        //2
        path.lineTo(topRightX, topRightY)

        //3
        when(topRight){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> path.lineTo(topRightX, topRightY + cornerRadius.toFloat())
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(topRightX - cornerRadius, topRightY,
                        topRightX + cornerRadius, topRightY + 2*cornerRadius), 270f, 90f, true)
                path.moveTo(topRightX + cornerRadius, topRightY + cornerRadius)
            }
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(topRightX - cornerRadius, topRightY,
                        topRightX + cornerRadius, topRightY + 2*cornerRadius), 180f, 90f, true)
                path.moveTo(topRightX - cornerRadius, topRightY + cornerRadius)
            }
        }
        //4
        path.lineTo(rect.right.toFloat(), bottomRightY - cornerRadius)
        //5
        when(bottomRight){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> path.lineTo(bottomRightX, bottomRightY)
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(bottomRightX - cornerRadius, bottomRightY - 2*cornerRadius,
                        bottomRightX + cornerRadius, bottomRightY), 0f, 90f, true)
                path.moveTo(bottomRightX, bottomRightY)
            }
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(bottomRightX - cornerRadius, bottomRightY - 2*cornerRadius,
                        bottomRightX + cornerRadius, bottomRightY), 90f, 90f, true)
                path.moveTo(bottomRightX, bottomRightY)
            }
        }
        //6
        path.lineTo(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY)
        //7
        when(bottomLeft){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> path.lineTo(bottomLeftX, bottomRightY - cornerRadius)
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(bottomLeftX - cornerRadius, bottomLeftY - 2 * cornerRadius,
                        bottomLeftX + cornerRadius, bottomLeftY), 90f, 90f, true)
                path.moveTo(bottomLeftX - cornerRadius, bottomLeftY - cornerRadius)
            }
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(bottomLeftX - cornerRadius, bottomLeftY - 2*cornerRadius,
                        bottomLeftX + cornerRadius, bottomLeftY), 0f, 90f, true)
                path.moveTo(bottomLeftX + cornerRadius, bottomLeftY - cornerRadius)
            }
        }
        //8
        path.lineTo(rect.left.toFloat(), topLeftY + cornerRadius)
        //9
        when(topLeft){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> path.lineTo(topLeftX, topLeftY)
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> path.arcTo(RectF(topLeftX - cornerRadius, topLeftY,
                        topLeftX + cornerRadius, topLeftY + 2*cornerRadius), 180f, 90f, true)
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> path.arcTo(RectF(topLeftX - cornerRadius, topLeftY,
                        topLeftX + cornerRadius, topLeftY + 2*cornerRadius), 270f, 90f, true)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to draw it with stroke, it seems all works as I expected.

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        val paint = Paint()
        paint.color = Color.RED
        //paint.strokeWidth = 3f
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.isAntiAlias = true

        val path = Path()

        path.fillType = Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD
        CustomShapes.rectangleWithRoundedCorners(path, Rect(100, 100, 600, 600), 50, CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE, CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE, CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE, CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE)
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
    }
```

[image: stroke, all corners outside]
But when I draw with fill type it fills as in picture below: 
[image]
I've tried all Path.FillTypes but none of them fills rectangle properly.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: But close() just add segment from current point to first point, isn't it?

Comment: ok for inside you have always 90 deg then for outside should not it be always -90 deg?

Comment: @pskink, thanks, you absolutely right, when i draw "outside" arc segment it's drawn from end segment point to start segment point and this causes breakup in path.

Comment: of course you need to change start angle too...

Answer (score 0):

@pskink rightly pointed that problem was because of wrong draw direction of "outside" arcs. 
Corrected drawing code:

```
        path.reset()
        //1
        path.moveTo(topLeftX, topLeftY)
        //2
        path.lineTo(topRightX, topRightY)

        //3
        when(topRight){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> path.lineTo(topRightX, topRightY + cornerRadius.toFloat())
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(topRightX - cornerRadius, topRightY,
                        topRightX + cornerRadius, topRightY + 2*cornerRadius), 270f, 90f, false)
                //path.moveTo(topRightX + cornerRadius, topRightY + cornerRadius)
            }
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(topRightX - cornerRadius, topRightY,
                        topRightX + cornerRadius, topRightY + 2*cornerRadius), 270f, -90f, false)
                //path.moveTo(topRightX - cornerRadius, topRightY + cornerRadius)
            }
        }
        //4
        path.lineTo(rect.right.toFloat(), bottomRightY - cornerRadius)
        //5
        when(bottomRight){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> path.lineTo(bottomRightX, bottomRightY)
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(bottomRightX - cornerRadius, bottomRightY - 2*cornerRadius,
                        bottomRightX + cornerRadius, bottomRightY), 0f, 90f, false)
                //path.moveTo(bottomRightX, bottomRightY)
            }
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(bottomRightX - cornerRadius, bottomRightY - 2*cornerRadius,
                        bottomRightX + cornerRadius, bottomRightY), 180f, -90f, false)
                //path.moveTo(bottomRightX, bottomRightY)
            }
        }
        //6
        path.lineTo(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY)
        //7
        when(bottomLeft){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> path.lineTo(bottomLeftX, bottomRightY - cornerRadius)
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(bottomLeftX - cornerRadius, bottomLeftY - 2 * cornerRadius,
                        bottomLeftX + cornerRadius, bottomLeftY), 90f, 90f, false)
                //path.moveTo(bottomLeftX - cornerRadius, bottomLeftY - cornerRadius)
            }
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> {
                path.arcTo(RectF(bottomLeftX - cornerRadius, bottomLeftY - 2*cornerRadius,
                        bottomLeftX + cornerRadius, bottomLeftY), 90f, -90f, false)
                //path.moveTo(bottomLeftX + cornerRadius, bottomLeftY - cornerRadius)
            }
        }
        //8
        path.lineTo(rect.left.toFloat(), topLeftY + cornerRadius)
        //9
        when(topLeft){
            CornerType.NOT_ROUNDED -> path.lineTo(topLeftX, topLeftY)
            CornerType.ROUNDED_INSIDE -> path.arcTo(RectF(topLeftX - cornerRadius, topLeftY,
                        topLeftX + cornerRadius, topLeftY + 2*cornerRadius), 180f, 90f, false)
            CornerType.ROUNDED_OUTSIDE -> path.arcTo(RectF(topLeftX - cornerRadius, topLeftY,
                        topLeftX + cornerRadius, topLeftY + 2*cornerRadius), 0f, -90f, false)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: final result]